# Install Xbuntu 18.04.5 WITHOUT ANY KERNEL

Tags: kernel

I need to install Xbuntu 18.04.5 WITHOUT ANY KERNEL, or remove ALL kernels right after installation.
The explanation is very simple - the system is supposed to work ONLY with the CUSTOM kernel, compiled specifically for this purpose.
Not only do I want to free up some disk space that I will never use, but I also want to not upgrade an unused kernel and avoid the filesystem swelling.
But I don't want to crash half the system because of dependencies.

Has anyone done something like this?

Comment: Impossible. You need at least 1 kernel always. The current one. Plus you are setting yourself up for failure: you also need the last kernel before the current one as a fallback.

Comment: @Rinzwind It is impossible to install without a kernel, but it is possible to achieve the result another way: install normally, install the custom kernel, remove the regular one.

Comment: Agree, but you could install as normal, then install your custom kernel, then re-boot to it, then delete the stock kernel. But it would be better to always keep at least one stock kernel, and boot to it for updates etc.

Comment: I was successful, though not without problems.
https://ubuntu.pl/forum/viewtopic.php?p=1035892#p1035892

Answer (score 6):

It is quite easy to have only a custom kernel.

1. Install Xubuntu normally.
2. Install your custom kernel.
3. Remove `linux-image-` and `linux-headers-` packages.